# Ansible (2.5.0) Module Failure - ios_user, ios_ping

Tags: python, networking, ansible, cisco, cisco-ios

I was in the middle of programming an Ansible playbook and suddenly I started getting a "Module Error" and I have no idea why. I tried each module individually in the CLI with every option. I ran a syntax check (`--syntax-check`) and there were no problems with that. I think this mught be a bug.

**"ios_facts" module works:**

```
$ ansible all -m ios_facts -i Resources/Inventory/hosts
```

> 10.20.30.111 | SUCCESS => {
>
> ```
> "ansible_facts": {
>     "ansible_net_all_ipv4_addresses": [
>         "10.20.30.111"
>     ], 
>     "ansible_net_all_ipv6_addresses": [], 
>     "ansible_net_filesystems": [
>         "flash:"
> (...)
> ```

**"ios_ping" returns this error:**

```
$ ansible all -m ios_ping -a"dest='1.1.1.1'" -i Resources/Inventory/hosts
```

> 10.20.30.111 | FAILED! => { "changed": false, 
>         "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_WOH7nd/ansible_module_ios_ping.py\", line 215, in \n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_WOH7nd/ansible_module_ios_ping.py\", line 151, in main\n    success, rx, tx, rtt = parse_ping(stats)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_WOH7nd/ansible_module_ios_ping.py\", line 200, in parse_ping\n    return rate.group(\"pct\"), rate.group(\"rx\"), rate.group(\"tx\"), rtt.groupdict()\nAttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'\n", "module_stdout": "", "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", "rc": 1}

**"ios_user" returns this error:**

> An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: ASwitch#
>
> 10.20.30.111 | FAILED! => {
>       "changed": false, 
>       "module_stderr": "Traceback (most recent call last):\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UX9ZWc/ansible_module_ios_user.py\", line 409, in \n    main()\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UX9ZWc/ansible_module_ios_user.py\", line 382, in main\n    have = map_config_to_obj(module)\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UX9ZWc/ansible_module_ios_user.py\", line 242, in map_config_to_obj\n    data = get_config(module, flags=['| section username'])\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UX9ZWc/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/network/ios/ios.py\", line 117, in get_config\n  File \"/tmp/ansible_UX9ZWc/ansible_modlib.zip/ansible/module_utils/connection.py\", line 146, in **rpc**\nansible.module_utils.connection.ConnectionError: show running-config | section username\r\n                              ^\r\n% Invalid input detected at '^' marker.\r\n\r\nASwitch#\n", 
>       "module_stdout": "", 
>       "msg": "MODULE FAILURE", 
>       "rc": 1
>   }

**IOS config:** [config.text](https://pastebin.com/s0VT1WBx)

**Ansible Inventory:** [Resources/Inventory/hosts](https://pastebin.com/3wc2ztjQ)

**Ansible Version:** `2.5.0`

**Cisco IOS version:** `12.2(55)SE`

The connection works fine and I also was able to execute the "ios_system" module. Do you guys have any idea what this might be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out, the **`ios_user`** module is not compatible with Cisco IOS version **12.2(55)SE** because it is using an output filter ("`section`") which is not available for this device's version. To fix this, I just had to substitute the word **"`section`"** with **"`include`"** in the `ansible/modules/network/ios/ios_user.py` file (the complete file path depends on your ansible instalation, because you might be using a virtual environment).
[Here is the module code](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ansible/ansible/devel/lib/ansible/modules/network/ios/ios_user.py). So that part of the the code then looked like this:

> ```
> def map_config_to_obj(module):
>     data = get_config(module, flags=['| include username'])
>
>    match = re.findall(r'^username (\S+)', data, re.M)
>     if not match:
>         return list()
> ```

The module now works as intendeed. As for the **`ios_ping`**, I've been trying to reverse engineer it's code and, in my opinion, has more then one bug. I think it is working only when the success rate is above `0%`.

Answer (score 1):

The second error suggests that

```
show running-config | section username
```

is not a valid command on your device. Can you try running it by hand, most likely it will also fail. I'd guess that your IOS is too old or too new for most ios_ modules (12.2-whatexactly are you running?). This could also explain the ping not working due to differences in command output.

Comment: I tried that command and my IOS does not have the "section" ouput modifier. My IOS version is **12.2(55)SE**. What do you think are my options here ?

Comment: From https://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios/fundamentals/command/reference/cf_book/cf_s1.html I get that 12.3 or 12.2(33)SRE should have it, maybe you can upgrade? Sorry I'm not really a Cisco guy and don't know if that's possible on this switch, or why 12.2(55) does not have features of (33)SRE.

Comment: Also, you can report it as a bug on the Ansible github: https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues - it sounds like it could be quite easily fixed by detecting the absence of the command and then get the info with "include" instead of "section".

Comment: Your suggestion of using "include" is also useful for other playbooks I'm working on. I don't think upgrading my IOS software is an option because I am working with a big group of switches and routers. Thank you anyway